# Can't connect to Extension Marketplace, Linux Manjaro 21.0.7

Tags: vscode-extensions

i have installed a fresh version of vscode in my new Manjaro installation.
Connection to the internet is active but i get the following error

> "We cannot connect to the Extension Marketplace at this time, please
> try again later."

When i open the developer console i get the following Errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery/extensionquery' from origin 'vscode-file://vscode-app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
workbench.desktop.main.js:2835 Error querying extensions gallery XHR failed
workbench.desktop.main.js:76 POST https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery/extensionquery net::ERR_FAILED
```

Can anyone help ;-(
What does that mean and how can i fix it?

Best wishes
Daniel

Comment: Are you using VSCode from Microsoft (which won't connect to https://open-vsx.org)?

Comment: I have installed VS Code via the Manjaro Repository. But now i have tried installing via Snapcraft and this works ;-) https://snapcraft.io/install/code/manjaro

Comment: Then you can post that as an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed VS Code via the Manjaro Repository. But now i have tried installing via Snapcraft and this works ;-)

https://snapcraft.io/install/code/manjaro