# vscode problem wiht extensions marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i downloaded arch linux and vscode, but when I want to download some extensions for them I get this message:

> `We cannot connect to the Extensions Marketplace at this time, please try again later.`

I googled and found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106350#issuecomment-692652621)

So, I went to network and that what i saw
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAtIl.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to Extension Marketplace, Linux Manjaro 21.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829345/cant-connect-to-extension-marketplace-linux-manjaro-21-0-7)

Comment: Yap, i just reinstall vscode from another repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same problem just reinstall vscode from official site or another repository